# Salesforce ForceClient never receives the response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, salesforce, salesforce-communities

We have recently upgraded the Salesforce `DeveloperForce.Force` framework from `1.3.2` to `2.0.7` via nuget as part of Sitecore Upgrade to 9.0.2. After that, calling `QueryAsync` method gives no response. Not sure where  the response is going on. Here is the code snippet.

```
            try
            {
                var client = new ForceClient(instanceUrl, accessToken, apiVersion);

                var dealers = client.QueryAsync<DealerDto>(query).Result;

                return new QueryResponseDto<DealerDto> { TotalSize = dealers.TotalSize, Records = dealers.Records };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
```

Please note that, Authentication process is success and i'm able to get back the token, url and apiVersion. The same code is working with 1.3.2 version.

Does anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Can you share the query you're trying? Have you tried setting the api version manually? Did you test the query in workbench? Also, shameless plug, but try running your query with my nuget package: https://github.com/deesejohn/Reinforce

Comment: @JohnD, The query is simple select statement. I tried the code in new  console application and it is working absolutely fine. Api version - i have taken it from AuthenticationClient object.